# How to use #selector(myMethodName) in a protocol extension?

Tags: swift2, protocols

```
protocol LazyUpdateable {
    func waitToDoStuff()
    func myMethodName()
}


extension LazyUpdateable where Self: NSObject {
    func waitToDoStuff() {
        self.performSelector(#selector(myMethodName), withObject: nil, afterDelay: 1.5)
    }

    func myMethodName() {

    }
}
```

With this update i get the error `Argument of #selector refers to a method that is not exposed to objective c`, but if i go with the old `Selector("myMethodName")` i get a warning to change to the better way of doing it. Is it possible to use the `#selector()` in this case? It won't work with setting `@objc` on my protocol, i've tried it.

Here is a playground you can try that shows it does not work with setting `@objc`

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import XCPlayground


@objc protocol LazyUpdatable {
    optional func waitToDoStuff()
    optional func myMethodName()
}

extension LazyUpdatable where Self: UIViewController {
    func waitToDoStuff() {
        self.performSelector(#selector(myMethodName), withObject: nil, afterDelay: 1.5)
    }

    func myMethodName() {
        print("LOL")
    }
}


@objc
class AViewController: UIViewController, LazyUpdatable {
    func start() {
        waitToDoStuff()
    }
}

let aViewController = AViewController()
aViewController.start()

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic dispatching using #selector() or Selector() doesn't see your Swift protocol extension. Instead, try avoiding Objective-C altogether, if possible. You can achieve the same result using libdispatch:

```
protocol LazyUpdatable {

    func waitToDoStuff()
    func myMethodName()
}

extension LazyUpdatable {

    func waitToDoStuff() {
        let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.myMethodName()
        }
    }

    func myMethodName() {
        print("Aloha!")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, LazyUpdatable {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        waitToDoStuff()
    }
}
```

Granted, this is not as flexible as using selectors, but lets you use real Swift protocol extensions.

**EDIT:**
If you want to be able to cancel invoking the method call, try the following:

```
var lazyUpdatableCancelKey = UInt8(0)

protocol LazyUpdatable: class {

    func waitToDoStuff()
    func cancelDoingStuff()
    func myMethodName()
}

extension LazyUpdatable {

    func waitToDoStuff() {
        let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            if let shouldCancel = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &lazyUpdatableCancelKey) as? Bool where shouldCancel == true {
                return
            }
            self.myMethodName()
        }
    }

    func cancelDoingStuff() {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &lazyUpdatableCancelKey, true, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
    }

    func myMethodName() {
        print("Aloha!")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, LazyUpdatable {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        waitToDoStuff()

        let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1.4 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.cancelDoingStuff()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For XCode 8.2.1 and Swift 3.

You you can use the traditional `Selector("methodName")` like you have tried. Additionally you can silence the warning by wrapping it in parenthesis `Selector(("methodName"))`

Since everything is within your protocol it's less likely you'll make typos that will end up crashing